# No search in split json view, vscode 1.59

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not able to see user settings and workspace setting together also the search is missing in the split json view.

vscode version: 1.59

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bau4A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of split JSON settings editor was old and hard to maintain (discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125952#issue-917705621) so that code has been replaced by a new implementation. Being new, it lacks many of the features present in the old JSON editor. There is an issue open in official GitHub repo to track this

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130457